# AdventureWorks SSIS ETL to AdventureWorksDW Example/Demos

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse, adventureworks

- Win 2007
- SQL Server 2014
- Example database `AdventureWorks`, `AdventureWorksDW`
- MS Visual Studio 2013

I am after SSIS ETLs examples for AdventureWorks to AdventureWorksDW

I have searched GOOG and can not find 2014 version

Any ideas were I can find them?

Comment: You can check the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but the link only covers Database creation

Nothing there about ETLs between AdventureWorks to AdventureWorksDW (2014 verison)

NOTE: The release of 2008 R2 AdventureWorks set had the ETLs, but as you know a lot changed since 2012 release.